# IOS 7 Unable to change background image of search bar

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am unable to customise search bar in my IOS 7.

I was using following code to change search bar background in IOS6

```
for (UIView * v in sarchBar.subviews)
{
    if ([v isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField")])
    {
        v.superview.alpha = 0;
        UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sarchBar.frame];
        [containerView addSubview:v];
        [self.view addSubview:containerView];
        [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

secondly If I customises search Controller to remove default cancel button in search bar, It was working ok in IOS6, but with custom search Controller it is not searching in IOS7.

Comment: you are using private classes of apple, be careful: your app could be rejected by iStore

Comment: which one is private class?

Comment: yes I am able to change background, but for full customisation you need to subclass UISearchController and after subclassing search not working

Comment: UISearchBarTextField is private, there's no documentation at all, you can get the name class just checking subviews, but that doesn't mean you can use it directly. I'm telling you this 'couse i tried something similar once, and apple rejected my app, it's against Apple rules… but you can try, of course...

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you use a text field instead and change the background image because it is the sub-class and inherits the same property.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I might have misread the original question.. The below answer shows you how to safely obtain the `UITextField` from within a `UISearchBar`.

Looking back at your code, it looks as if you are trying to directly modify the view hierarchy of the `UISearchBar`. I know apple cracked down on doing such things on other UI elements in iOS 7 (like `UIAlertView`) but I'm not sure if they have done the same with the `UISearchBar`.

Regarding the Cancel Button.. Can't you just use the [`showsCancelButton`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/showsCancelButton) property on the `UISearchBar`?

---

I wrote the following category to try and obtain the `UITextField` from within the `UISearchBar`.

It works on iOS 7 but not tested on 6 (i don't see why it wouldn't)

**UISearchBar+BSSearchBar.h**

```
//
// Created by Liam Nichols on 07/04/2014.
// Copyright (c) 2014 Liam Nichols. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UISearchBar (BSSearchBar)

- (void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)color;

- (UITextField *)internalTextField;

@end
```

**UISearchBar+BSSearchBar.m**

```
//
// Created by Liam Nichols on 07/04/2014.
// Copyright (c) 2014 Liam Nichols. All rights reserved.
//

#import "UISearchBar+BSSearchBar.h"


@implementation UISearchBar (BSSearchBar)

- (void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    UITextField *textField = [self internalTextField];
    textField.textColor = color;
}

- (UITextField *)internalTextField
{
    return [UISearchBar findTextFieldInView:self];
}

+ (UITextField *)findTextFieldInView:(UIView *)view
{
    for (id subview in view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            return subview;
        }

        UITextField *subviewTextField = [UISearchBar findTextFieldInView:subview];
        if ([subviewTextField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            return subviewTextField;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this  for background image .. I hope it helps

```
 for(UIView *subView in [searchBarObj subviews]) {
    for(UIView *subSubView in [subView subviews]) {
        if([subSubView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
            [(UITextField *)subSubView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]]];
        }
    }
  }
```

Thanks ..